# Group nodes which are visually together

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am implementing force-directed graph in d3js.
I want to divide my graph into two halves and colour both the halves with different colour, after the network has been rendered and `forceSimulation` has completed.

What I am looking for is explained in image.
[image]

I am refering [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

I don't want to update the group field into my data as described in the link because my links are changing dynamically on several events which is also changing the orientation of the network and updating group field into the data is creating the groups of same nodes whether they are near or far from each other.

Currently, I am using the window coordinates to divide this.

```
const screenWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
const halfScreen = screenWidth / 2;
nodes.selectAll().attr("fill", function (d) {
  return d.x <  halfScreen ? "blue" : "green";
});
```

But this is not the good idea. I would love to know any other way that is possible to do this.

Comment: I understand you want to divide the nodes into two groups. Preferably each with half of the nodes, in which the distances between the nodes in each group is as small as possible. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. But the distances between nodes is changing on different events and want to do the same thing each time.

Comment: what is the deciding attribute to color blue or green? screen-x will not work because the graph can be rotated and translated.

Comment: I am searching for a proper deciding attribute to colour them. Just the nodes on left should be blue and nodes on right should be green. I want to change it when graph is rotated. But at times maximum nodes are on one side of the screen and are coloured same.

Answer (score 1):

So, my, interpretation of your question: you want to divide the nodes into two groups. Preferably each with half of the nodes, in which the distances between the nodes in each group is as small as possible.

The best algorithms for this that I know of are algorithms for constructing a "minimum spanning tree", for example, [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm).

Adapting the algorithm to your problem, you start with (a copy of) the graph, having no edges. You then add the edges, sorted by length, smallest first. You stop doing this as soon as you have exactly two [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)). These connected components form groups in which nodes have a small mutual distance.

However, the groups probably won't have the same number of nodes, and I don't guarantee that this gives you the smallest mutual distance.

EDIT:
If there is more than 1 connected component, you could group them by starting with two empty groups and repeatedly adding a component (largest first) to the group that has the smallest number of nodes. This will probably give you more or less equal groups.

Comment: It is failing for some cases when I have graph as a single component and no connected components or when there are more than 1 connected components.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit?